# USB3 host controller type for PC purchase (Azure Kinect DK)

Tags: usb, computer-building, hardware-rec, kinect

**Question**

How can I check that a Windows computer that I want to order will have a USB3 host controller from Intel, Texas Instruments (TI), or Renesas?

What spec determines the USB3 host controller? Will selecting an Intel CPU and an Intel motherboard chipset (e.g. [Intel® Z390](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/133293/intel-z390-chipset.html)) guarantee that the PC will have an Intel USB3 host controller?

---

**Context**

I want to buy a PC to run a specific device (Azure Kinect DK) that lists the [following as a system requirement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kinect-dk/troubleshooting#usb3-host-controller-compatibility):

> USB3 host controller compatibility
>
> If the device is not enumerating
>   under device manager, it may be because it's plugged into an
>   unsupported USB3 controller.
>
> For the Azure Kinect DK on **Windows, Intel, Texas Instruments (TI), and
>   Renesas** are the *only host controllers that are supported.*

[image: Intel USB host controller in device manager. Image source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kinect-dk/troubleshooting#usb3-host-controller-compatibility]

(Note that the [minimum specs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kinect-dk/system-requirements) also specify a Seventh Gen Intel® CoreTM i5 Processor.)

Comment: As far as I know those 3 are the only usb 3.0 host controllers being used on motherboards.

Comment: Easy way would go to the support page for that model PC and look at the usb 3.0 drivers being offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB 3.x host controllers for Windows must be compliant to Intel xHCI specifications. Today they all are supported by stock Microsoft xHCI (eXtensible Host Controller Interface) driver. And yes, ordering any recent Intel-based mainboard (like the latest and greatest Z390) will guarantee that it does have at least two Intel-based controllers. In many cases Intel boards would have additional xHCI controller based on AsMedia chip (like ASM1142) which provides the missing Gen2 speeds on usually two extra ports.

I don't think you can find any mainboard with Renesas (NEC) or TI host chips. Renesas is way behind current USB development and has only USB 3.0 speeds, so there is no reason to put these chips if Z390 provides all equivalent functionality. And I haven't seen on-board TI in my life. There must be really something strange with your specific device if it needs so specific and rare chips as TI and Renesas.

Comment: Any official documentation/specification would be helpful for further reading.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, which specs? https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technical-specifications/extensible-host-controler-interface-usb-xhci.pdf The number and type of USB controllers on a board is a choice of OEM.